# Why rotation transformation create distortion effect on subviews in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, cgaffinetransform

In my SwiftUI application, for special reasons, I create a view with UIKit with the `makeUIView` function. I thus create sub views to display several elements. For one of these views, I apply a rotation to it with `CGAffineTransform`. But I have an unwanted effect that appears when this view is rotated. Looks like a 3D effect applied in addition to the rotation effect.

I tried using `CGAffineTransform.identity`, but another problem appears: the rotation does a full turn again (which is why I wanted to use UIKit with the `CGAffineTransform` to benefit from a rotation by matrix, that solve the problem).

The unwanted effect:

[image: Screen shot]

Code:

```
struct SonarView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var angle: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    var offset: CGFloat
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var imageName: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {    
        // Container
        let container = UIView()
        container.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        container.layer.borderWidth = 0
        container.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.521568656, green: 0.1098039225, blue: 0.05098039284, alpha: 1)
      
        // Subcontainer
        let subContainer = UIView()
        subContainer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: offset, height: offset)
        subContainer.center = CGPoint(x: container.frame.size.width / 2, y: container.frame.size.height / 2)
        subContainer.layer.borderWidth = 0
        subContainer.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 1)
            
        container.addSubview(subContainer)
      
        // Target container
        let targetContainer = UIView()
        targetContainer.frame = CGRect.init(x: (width / 2) - (36 / 2), y: -18, width: 32 + 4, height: 32 + 4)
      
        subContainer.addSubview(targetContainer)
      
        // Overlay
        let overlay = UIView()
        overlay.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32 + 4, height: 32 + 4)
        overlay.layer.cornerRadius = (32 + 5) / 2
        overlay.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryLight")?.cgColor
        overlay.layer.opacity = 0.4
        overlay.layer.borderWidth = 2
        overlay.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")?.cgColor
      
        targetContainer.addSubview(overlay)
      
        // Circle
        let circle = UIView()
        circle.frame = CGRect.init(x: 2, y: 2, width: 32, height: 32)
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = 32 / 2
        circle.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryLight")?.cgColor
        circle.layer.borderWidth = 2
        circle.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")?.cgColor
            
        targetContainer.addSubview(circle)
      
        // Image
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: imageName)
        imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 9, y: 9, width: 32 - 14, height: 32 - 14)
      
        targetContainer.addSubview(imageView)
      
        return container
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {        
            // Mise à jour de la taille de la subview
            uiView.subviews[0].frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: offset, height: offset)
            uiView.subviews[0].center = CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height / 2)
        
            // Mise à jour de l'angle de la subview
            uiView.subviews[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle.degreesToRadians)
        
            // Mise à jour de la position sur l'axe X de la cible
            uiView.subviews[0].subviews[0].frame.origin.x = (offset / 2) - (36 / 2)
        }, completion: nil)
      
        // Animation de l'overlay
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.75, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            uiView.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
        }, completion: nil)
      
        // Mise à jour de l'icône
        let imageView = uiView.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UIImageView }
        imageView[0].image = UIImage(systemName: imageName)
        imageView[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -angle.degreesToRadians)
    }
}
```

So I don't know why this effect appear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems another solution is to rotate the SwiftUI `View`, instead of the `UIView` inside, with `.rotationEffect(.degrees(<#T##degrees: Double##Double#>))`. Currently the UIView is trying to fit within the width/frame of the SwiftUI view.

Weirdly, setting `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` worked for me...

| Without | With |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |